# How to use newest MSVC compiler (2017) in old Visual Studio (2010)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a weak computer and the interface of modern Visual Studios (2015/2017) works extremely slowly on it. I'm satisfied with the speed and functionality of the interface of Visual Studio 2010, but I want to use the latest features of C++. 
How can I connect the compiler and debugger of VS2017 toolset to the VS2010 IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that. You can try changing the toolset directories. But I highly doubt that will work.
But I can suggest other approaches:
- switch off intellisence and other features of VS
- uninstall VS packages you do not need
- Try Visual Studio Code instead. If you are not tied to Windows, get a Linux OS and use it with Visual Studio Code.
- Otherwise use another editor to code in (like notepad++) and use only the command line to build projects (you cant use the debugger in that case)